# How has responsibility to instantiate different view for different models?

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, cocoa-design-patterns

In a MVC approach, who is responsible to create a right view for one specific model?

I have two classes `C` and `D` both subclass of `A`. My controller knows how to manage instances of `A` but it needs to instantiate differents views when objects are instances of `C` or `D`.

I have three possible approacs:
I can move the complexity on the model, adding a method like `getView` but i think the model has to be more light as possible.

I can move the complexity on the controller, adding a switch based on model's class, but in this way the controller has to know all internals detail of the model.

I can move the complexity on the view, adding a metod like createViewForModel() but i have to put a switch inside this method...and is not a good thing.

Can someone share a link or a discussion about this topic? thanks

Comment: If the layout of the view depends on the model, I'd do the custom initializer approach (move it onto the view).  Otherwise controller.

Comment: are you talking about a Factory for View? And it's ok for you to have a switch inside that factory on Model Class? (or a custom `ModelType` property).

Comment: If all you have are two specific instances, just make 2 separate initializers for the view, or dispense two different views, even, from the controller.